# Kendo grid export to pdf

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm relatively new to mvc and also kendo library. In my project I need a way to export data from Kendo Grid( http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/index.html ) to PDF.

I actually found a pretty good example on how to do that but in it Entity framework is used to pass data to the grid. Here is the example: http://www.kendoui.com/code-library/mvc/grid/export-grid-to-pdf.aspx .

In my project I used NHibernate to mapp the data and later pass it to the model in a View.

Unfortunately I don't fully understand the code in the example and I cant figure out how to change my code .

Example:

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using KendoMVCWrappers.Models;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using System.Collections;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;

namespace KendoMVCWrappers.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private NwEntities db = new NwEntities();

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to kick-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
        {
           // DataSourceRequest i = request;
            return Json(db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request)); 
        }

        public FileResult Export([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
        {
            IEnumerable products = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;

            // step 1: creation of a document-object
            var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10, 10, 10, 10);

            //step 2: we create a memory stream that listens to the document
            var output = new MemoryStream();
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, output);

            //step 3: we open the document
            document.Open();

            //step 4: we add content to the document
            var numOfColumns = 4;
            var dataTable = new PdfPTable(numOfColumns);

            dataTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;

            dataTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 2;
            dataTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            // Adding headers
            dataTable.AddCell("Product ID");
            dataTable.AddCell("Product Name");
            dataTable.AddCell("Unit Price");
            dataTable.AddCell("Quantity Per Unit");

            dataTable.HeaderRows = 1;
            dataTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;

            foreach (Product prod in products)
            {
                dataTable.AddCell(prod.ProductID.ToString());
                dataTable.AddCell(prod.ProductName);
                dataTable.AddCell(prod.UnitPrice.ToString());
                dataTable.AddCell(prod.QuantityPerUnit);
            }

            // Add table to the document
            document.Add(dataTable);

            //This is important don't forget to close the document
            document.Close();

            // send the memory stream as File
            return File(output.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "Products.pdf");

        }


    }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@model IEnumerable<KendoMVCWrappers.Models.Product>

@(
 Html.Kendo().Grid(Model).Name("Grid")
                .DataSource(ds => ds.Ajax()
                                .Model(m =>
                                {
                                    m.Id(p=>p.ProductID);                              
                                })
                       .Read(r => r.Action("Read", "Home"))
                )
                .ToolBar(toolBar => 
                    toolBar.Custom()
                        .Text("Export To PDF")
                        .HtmlAttributes(new { id = "export" })
                        .Url(Url.Action("Export", "Home", new { page = 1, pageSize = "~", filter = "~", sort = "~" }))
                )
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductID);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.ProductName);
                    columns.Bound(p => p.UnitPrice).Format("{0:c}");
                    columns.Bound(p => p.QuantityPerUnit);
                })
                .Events(ev => ev.DataBound("onDataBound"))
                .Pageable(paging => paging
       .Input(false)
       .Numeric(true)
       .Info(true)
       .PreviousNext(true)
       .PageSizes(new int[]{6, 12, 100 }) 
       .Refresh(true)
       )
    .Sortable() 
    .Scrollable(scr=>scr.Height(330)) 
    .Filterable()    
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
)

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onDataBound(e) {
        var grid = $('#Grid').data('kendoGrid');

        // ask the parameterMap to create the request object for you
        var requestObject = (new kendo.data.transports["aspnetmvc-server"]({ prefix: "" }))
        .options.parameterMap({
            page: grid.dataSource.page(),
            sort: grid.dataSource.sort(),
            filter: grid.dataSource.filter()
        });

        // Get the export link as jQuery object
        var $exportLink = $('#export');

        // Get its 'href' attribute - the URL where it would navigate to
        var href = $exportLink.attr('href');

        // Update the 'page' parameter with the grid's current page
        href = href.replace(/page=([^&]*)/, 'page=' + requestObject.page || '~');

        // Update the 'sort' parameter with the grid's current sort descriptor
        href = href.replace(/sort=([^&]*)/, 'sort=' + requestObject.sort || '~');

        // Update the 'pageSize' parameter with the grid's current pageSize
        href = href.replace(/pageSize=([^&]*)/, 'pageSize=' + grid.dataSource._pageSize);

        //update filter descriptor with the filters applied

        href = href.replace(/filter=([^&]*)/, 'filter=' + (requestObject.filter || '~'));

        // Update the 'href' attribute
        $exportLink.attr('href', href);
    }
</script>
```

If I understand correctly Read function is used to pass data from Products database to the grid. DataSource request object is created with the javascript ?

How can I alter my code if I dont have database model like Products ?

In my project I use a Repository to get all the data I need to an IList. How can I use the example above to do something similar to:

```
IEnumerable products = db.Products.ToDataSourceResult(request).Data;
```

in my code below?

Repo:

public class CzasPracyMaszynRepository
{

```
public IList<CzasPracyMaszyn> GetCzasPracyMaszyn()
{
    using (ISession session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
    {

        var myList = session.Query<CzasPracyMaszyn>();


        return myList.ToList();
    }
}
```

}

Model:

```
public class CzasPracyMaszyn
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual string STANOWISKO { get; set; }
        public virtual int CZASPRACY { get; set; }
        public virtual int CZASAWARII { get; set; }
        public virtual int AWARIAFORMY { get; set; }
        public virtual int AWARIAROBOTA { get; set; }
        public virtual int AWARIAWTRYSKARKI { get; set; }
        public virtual int MOKRYSUROWIEC { get; set; }
        public virtual int PUSTE { get; set; }

    }
```

Controller:

public class TabeleController : Controller
{

```
CzasPracyMaszynRepository _repositoryCzasPracyMaszyn;


public TabeleController()
{
    _repositoryCzasPracyMaszyn = new CzasPracyMaszynRepository();

}


public ActionResult CzasPracyMaszynTabela()
{
    IList<CzasPracyMaszyn> CzasPracyMaszyn = _repositoryCzasPracyMaszyn.GetCzasPracyMaszyn();
    return View(CzasPracyMaszyn);
}
```

}

I know all of this is pretty vague but I did my best to describe my problem.